# Subtract integer-variable with dictionary or list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subtraction

**Hello! I am trying to subtract an integer-variable with all values in my dictionary. I've even tried converting the dict to a list. Nothing seems to work for me.**

I tried doing this just so see if it works, and it does work for one item in my expenses-dictionary, but how do I get all values from the dictionary and subtract it with my budget?

```
budget = budget - expenses["Rent"]
```

**The error I'm getting:** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Can you include the `expenses` `dict` in your question?

Comment: @match My expenses-dict is an empty dictionary. I add an item from an input.

Comment: Please then show the rest of your code, including the `input` and any loops etc, so we can see how the `dict` is constructed, and how you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dict called `expenses`. Unfortunately, its entries are strings.

The easiest thing to do is

```
budget -= sum(float(v) for k, v in expenses.items())
```

where we iterate over all entries of `expenses`, turn their values into a float (which bears problems on its own when using it with monetary values, but I do so for simplicity), sum them together and subtract this sum from the budget.

Answer (score -1):

```
budget = ...
expenses = {...}

for expense in expenses:
    budget -= float(expenses[expense])
```

Comment: Please remember to include an explanation when contributing answers.